# Change default print settings

Tags: samsung, android-12, printing

I'm printing from my Samsung Galaxy Note10+ to a Xerox VersaLink C405 and the default print settings are not what I want:

[image: Print settings dialog]

(Ignore the number of pages; this is just to serve as an example.)

I want to use Letter paper and double-sided printing as default. But changes to the settings here are not retained for future jobs. I could not find anything in the system settings or the "More options" dialog that would let me set the defaults. I can otherwise print without issues.

The phone is running One UI 4.1 (Android 12) and has the Xerox print service plugin installed. Is there some way to change the default print settings?